# Object expected error in IE8 version 8.0.7601

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

This is my first question on StackOverflow. The problem I am facing is I am trying to use the `datepicker` gadget in the textbox. It's working fine in Firefox, Chrome and IE v8.0.6001 but it is not working in IE v8.0.7601.

### External resources:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

### Datepicker script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    var count = document.getElementById('i_value').value;

    for(var i=0;i<=count;i++)
    {
        $( "#mgf_date"+i ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    }
 });();

</script>
```

### Textbox:

```
<input type='text' 
       id='mgf_date".$i."'
       name='mgf_date[]' 
       value='".$row1['mfg_date']."'   
       class='text_box1' 
       readonly 
       size='15'>
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: For which object/line does it throw the error?

Comment: It could be this line: `});();` try changing it to `})();`

Comment: For which object/line does it throw the error?
it throws the error at this line
$(function() {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    console.log('jQuery is working');

    $('.text_box1').each(function(i)
    { console.log('Woking for input:'+i);
        $( "#mgf_date"+i ).datepicker({
           changeMonth: true,
           changeYear: true
        });
    });
 });
 </script>
```

Check your console now, if it isn't showing any message like "jQuery is working", make sure your jQuery is not conflicting with any other jQuery function.

Comment: The OP is using `document.getElementById('i_value')` and you're using `$('.text_box1')`. Can you spot the mistake?

Comment: The syntax of both is correct. here i have used the common class ".text_box1" for all date pickers. .each function of jquery checks total number of that classes and loops through it. you can find further info here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: i tried the above thing, i am not getting any message like "jquery is working" then for addition information i have one more gadget for auto complete js in my code,but i don't think any jquery conflicts,

here is the included js for autocomplete

`<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/countries.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/demo.js"></script>`

Comment: Well if you are not getting the message "jquery is working", your jquery is probably not working here. Try changing `$(function...` to `jQuery(function...` or make a copy of `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` just above your script to make sure no other script is causing this issue.